# Img src not loaded in Outlook email

Tags: html, email, outlook, gmail, html-email

I send the same email to gmail (the image is loaded correctly) and outlook (Failed to load the given URL).

In gmail i have this html code:

```
http://xxx/~mgxzbmdx/joomla/images/stories/virtuemart/vendor/logo.png
```

In Outlook this one:

```
https://dub113.mail.live.com/Handlers/ImageProxy.mvc?bicild=&canary=nUc%2fUMnrf0l9V5rzT3XB4Cb5axSzPUBWqwI5uP2ZjrU%3d0&url=http%3a%2f%2fx.x.x.x%2f%7emgxzbmdx%2fjoomla%2fimages%2fstories%2fvirtuemart%2fvendor%2flogo.png
```

Any idea about the reason?

Comment: How are you sending the email? Are you using an email service, and if so, are they adding any sort of tracking?

Comment: @John, through virtuemart component and joomla. PHP mail

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the file type.

HTML emails should only use .gif or .jpg.

Try with a new picture format. I suppose you use a .png file because it has transparency? It saddens me that I have to tell you this, but you'll be better off faking transparency with split images in nested tables. That's the only way for a html-email not to break.

Comment: I use PNG pretty much exclusively. They work fine in email except in older versions of Lotus Notes.

Comment: No, the problem still exists.

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue lies with your method/software. Looks like your `/` are getting converted to `%2f` which gmail seems to be smart enough to interpret, but Outlook is not. See if there is something in Virtuemart or Joomla that you can turn off link encoding or something like that.